# Get x/y positions of nth item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how to get the X or Y position of nth item in RecyclerView. This is easy to do if the item is currently within the visible range. However, when the view is currently off the screen (e.g., current visible items range on the RecyclerView is 4 to 7, while the item I am interested in is, say, 1 or 10), there seems to be no way to get that value.

Here's what I have tried. I have the following three fields:

```
private RecyclerView rv;

/* The Layout Manager of rv */
private LinearLayoutManager llm;

/* The data to be shown in the RecyclerView. */
private String[] data = {"0","1","2",...,"9"};
```

I have the items "2" to "5" shown on the screen, and I want to get the X/Y position of the item "9", which is currently off the screen. So I tried the following:

```
int index = 9;
View v = rv.getChildAt(index);
View v2 = llm.getChildAt(index);
```

Unfortunately, both `v` and `v2` are null. The reason for it seems to be that while the size of `data` is 10, the childCount of `rv` and `llm` is whatever the number of views currently visible on the screen, as evidenced by the following:

```
int count = rv.getChildCount();
int count2 = llm.getChildCount();
```

Both variables are 4 (the number of views currently visible; i.e., "2" to "5"). Since the size of the recyclerView is 4, and I want to look up the item at index 9, I get null returned above.

Comment: you cannot, what is the reason for getting x/y positions of non visible items?

Comment: "The reason for it seems to be that while the size of `data` is 10, the childCount of `rv` and `llm` is whatever the number of views currently visible on the screen" - That's correct, more or less. If the items are all the same size, you could easily determine what an off-screen `View`'s position would be, if you really need, by getting the position of one on-screen, and figuring from the position difference and dimension.

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your comment. Would it help if I tell the reason I need those values?

Comment: @MikeM. Unfortunately, my RecyclerView items are all different sizes. I guess I should go with HorizontalScrollView combined with LinearLayout. I don't have many item views to display and they are all very simple views anyway so not being able to recycle views shouldn't be a big problem...

Comment: i think so as it seems to be a typical XY problem

Comment: I have just conceived another possible hack solution. Ill try it out and if it solves my problem i'll post it here as an answer. i domno if it'll help the future readers of this post but  ill do it anyway.

Comment: @pskink The reason I need those values is because I want to smooth-scroll the Recycler View to an arbitrary X position in such a way that the item I am interested in is positioned at the center of the visible width of the recycler view. This is something I cannot achieve by `rv.smoothScrollToPosition(positionOfTheItem)`.

Comment: so you should use `LayoutManager#startSmoothScroll` with your custom `SmoothScroller`, most likely `LinearSmoothScroller`

Answer (score 50):

I got perfect `x` and `y` of every item in recycler view using following:

```
int[] originalPos = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(originalPos);
//or view.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos)
int x = originalPos[0];
int y = originalPos[1];
```

Comment: i am getting 0 and 0

Comment: @Fudge maybe you're calling the method before the layout is computed?

Comment: use viewItem.doOnLayout{ ... }

Comment: That will give you first item position, what if I want to get 3rd or 4th item y position?

Answer (score 3):

Pal gajjar's answer is correct... **You can not** get the coordinates of recycled views by the simple reason **they aren't rendered yet, they haven't been created at this point**. You have to check if the view exist in the first place using `recyclerview.getChildAt(intValueHere)`...if it's different from null it means its close to the currently displayed child position and its partially rendered holded in memory...at this point, and only at this point in which views are holded in memory you're able to use the view. You should read how a recyclerview works and how the layout manager recycle the views to understand what's really going on... -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview