# Get position of 'x' item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to get x/y of an item of a recycler view. 
mRecyclerView.getChildAt(1) gives the child visible at position 1.
I want to get the list child at 1st position to perform some operation when it reaches 0,0.

```
if(mRecyclerView.getChildAt(1).getTop() == 0){

//do some operation

}
```

How could I achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004369/get-x-y-positions-of-nth-item-in-recyclerview?rq=1

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar, I want the top position of a particular item, say item at position 2, but no solution regarding this is provided there.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 ways to achieve it:

1. Create your own `LayoutManager` (that will extend `LinearLayoutManager` for example), attach it to yours `RecyclerView` and get `RecyclerView` first child position on scroll.

   ```
   public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

   //Constructor stuff

   @Override
   public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
       if (getChildAt(1).getTop() == 0) {
           // do stuff...
       }
       return super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
   }

   @Override
   public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
       super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
       // check your stuff here too. It'll be called when new views appeared
   }
   }
   ```
2. Attach scroll listener to `RecyclerView` and get views position there.

   ```
   RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
               RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(1);
               View view = holder.itemView;
               if (view.getTop() == 0){
                   //...
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: what is this 'binding'??

Comment: getChildAt(1) is giving the 1st child that is visible on screen

Comment: @AshishJohn binding in my case was ViewDataBinding object

Comment: Yes, `getChildAt(1)` will always give you first child at screen because of how `RecyclerView` works. You see, `RecyclerView` don't keep views when they are off-screen, it'll "recycle" them for further usage. This is main benefit of `RecyclerView` - you'll always have amount of views inflated which you need. If you don't believe me - run layout inspector (from Android Studio) and watch views hierarchy.